# Javascript timeout then reveal html

Tags: javascript

I'd like a button to initiate a timer then reveal another button after 8 seconds. This code doesn't work.

```html
<button id="wait" onclick="setTimeout(waitFunction, 8000)">Wait 8 seconds</button>
<script>
  function waitFunction() {
    document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = "<a href=" / confirm "><button>RevealButton</button></a>";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You're breaking your string here: `"<a href=" / confirm ">` - your console should have reported that error

Answer (score 0):

you have a mismatch quote in the href - also a good idea to clear out timeouts:

```html
<button id="wait" onclick="waitFunction()">Wait 8 seconds</button>
<script>
function waitFunction() {
  clearTimeout(window.waitFunctionTimeout);
  window.waitFunctionTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = "<a href=' / confirm '><button>RevealButton</button></a>";
  },8000);
    
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the #setTimeout function. See example:

https://jsfiddle.net/tdzckwsb/4/

https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // Do something here
}, timeout in milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put text inside `href` attribute you should put whole text in `'` for ex:

`'<a href = "/confirm"><button>RevealButton</button></a>'`

You can freely use `"` in `'`